# Dojox.widget.standby: Standby spinner widget not being created in IBM ODM 8.11.1 Decision Center customization

Tags: dojo, ibm-odm

We have customized the decisioncenter.war file creating new tabs and functionality.
When testing this on DC 8.9.2, it all works fine.
When moving to DC 8.11.1, the standby widget is not being created and is causing the code to stop before API calls for updating rules.
We have removed the standby widget and then the code all works fine, so the only compatibility issue we are facing is with this widget.

Declaration in html:

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="rateScheduleStandby"
        data-dojo-type="dojox/widget/Standby"
        data-dojo-props="target: 'rateScheduleTabSection'"></div>
```

Null value when called in the code:

[image]

What could be causing the standby widget to not being created in 8.11.1, when it works in 8.9.2.
I have looked at IBM Docs but cannot find information on anything that changed specifically in this regard.

Comment: What is the value of `params.target`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your problem is to modify your query to search for `params.target` instead of `target` in your JS code. I can't be more specific because there is no JS to look at. But in your dev tools, the params property pretty clearly contains a target that appears to be the one you're looking for. I use Dojo a lot and sometimes the properties appear in `params`, sometimes `panel`, sometimes at the root level.